# Why does the pole of $\frac{1-e^{2z}}{z^3}$ have order $2$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Why does pole at $z=0$ have order $2$, I ask this because as far as I can see it would have order $3$ as the denominator is of order $3$.

But when I input it into wolfram alpha it says it has order $2$. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried developping your function as a Taylor series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because 
$$\frac{1-e^{2z}}{z^3} = 2\frac{1-e^{2z}}{2z}\frac{1}{z^2} $$
and $\frac{1-e^{2z}}{2z}$ goes to $-1$ when $z$ goes to $0$.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

$$
e^{2z} =1 +2z+\frac{(2z)^2}{2!}+\cdots
$$
So
$$
\frac{1-e^{2z}}{z^3}=-\frac{\left(2+\frac{4z}{2}+\cdots \right)}{z^2}
$$
revealing the pole of order 2 at $z=0$.